# How to know when a process created by Process.Start() was closed?

Tags: c#, process, system-calls

I'm using this:

```
var proc2 = Process.Start(Path.GetFullPath(filename));
proc2.Exited += (_, __) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("closed!");
};
```

But I close the window and don't get `MessageBox.Show("closed!");`. How to fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the process actually ended?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set [`Process.EnableRaisingEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) to **true**.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to set the `EnableRaisingEvents` to true.

Also, you may want to create a Process with the constructor, set the ProcessStartInfo and then call Start after you register to listen to the event.  Otherwise you have a race condition where the Process exits before you even register to listen for the event (unlikely I know, but not mathematically impossible).

```
var process = new Process();

process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.GetFullPath(filename));
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

process.Exited += (a, b) =>
{
  MessageBox.Show("closed!");
};

process.Start();
```

Answer (score 4):

you forget  Enable Events

```
Process p;
p = Process.Start("cmd.exe");
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Exited += (sender, ea) =>
            {
                  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Cmd was Exited");
            };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fire the alert after `proc2.WaitForExit()`

Comment: It has an overload method which you can specify a timeout. Unfortunately it won't kill your process, it will just move on