# uninstalling an application and then installing another one using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to uninstall an application from the system and install a new version of it.

I tried out using Process.start and WaitForExit method in c# code

```
var process1 = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\unins000.exe");
process1.WaitForExit();
var process2 = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\abc\Downloads\Programs\cpu-z_1.71-setup-en.exe");
```

When the code runs, the setup file for the cpu-z_1.71 launches before the uninstaller exit.

How can i make the installer to wait until I press the OK button of the complete uninstallation dialog box.

Is it possible to do the above task using process or should I use some alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a method from below articles.

- [How to know when a process created by Process.Start() was closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920964/how-to-know-when-a-process-created-by-process-start-was-closed)
- [Process waitForExit() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688239/process-waitforexit-doesnt-work)

and this code can be a method.

```
private void RunNotePad()
{
    Process p1 = new Process("notepad.exe");
    p1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    //when process exit, excute ProcessExited function.
    p1.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExited);
    p1.Start();
}

public void ProcessExited(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    //start to install a new version
}
```

Comment: when I try the above code I get an error stating System.Diagnostic.Process does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Maybe it's a difference of NET framwork version. You can find some sample codes using Process class in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried it, but it still pops up the installation prompt for the new version before I could click the last dialog box of the uninstallation of the old version

Comment: Can you post your code, again? I've test my code, but it's works.

Comment: private void Rununinstaller()
        {
            
            Process process1;
            process1 = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\unins000.exe");
            process1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process1.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExited);
            //process1.Start();
        }

        public void ProcessExited(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            var process2 = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\abc\Downloads\Programs\cpu-z_1.71-setup-en.exe");
        }

Comment: I think its the cpu's uninstallation problem which wants a user to click on ok after uninstallation. I tried this with another application and it works :) Thanks CodeDreamer